# PySpark DataFrame Code for an HiveQL that takes 3-4 hours

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, rank

The following HiveQL code takes about 3 to 4 hours and I am trying effectively convert this into a pyspark data frame code. Any dataframe experts input is appreciated a lot.

```
INSERT overwrite table dlstage.DIBQtyRank_C11 PARTITION(fiscalyearmonth) 
    SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT a.matnr, a.werks, a.periodstartdate, a.fiscalyear, a.fiscalmonth,b.dy_id, MaterialType,(COALESCE(a.salk3,0)) salk3,(COALESCE(a.lbkum,0)) lbkum, sum(a.valuatedquantity) AS valuatedquantity, sum(a.InventoryValue) AS InventoryValue, 
            rank() over (PARTITION by dy_id, werks, matnr order by a.max_date DESC) rnk, sum(stprs) stprs, max(peinh) peinh, fcurr,fiscalyearmonth 
            FROM dlstage.DIBmsegFinal a 
            LEFT JOIN dlaggr.dim_fiscalcalendar b ON a.periodstartdate=b.fmth_begin_dte WHERE a.max_date >= b.fmth_begin_dte AND a.max_date <= b.dy_id and 
            fiscalYearmonth = concat(fyr_id,lpad(fmth_nbr,2,0)) 
            GROUP BY a.matnr, a.werks,dy_id, max_date, a.periodstartdate, a.fiscalyear, a.fiscalmonth, MaterialType, fcurr, COALESCE(a.salk3,0), COALESCE(a.lbkum,0),fiscalyearmonth) a 
            WHERE a.rnk=1 and a.fiscalYear = '%s'" %(year) + " and a.fiscalmonth ='%s'" %(mnth)
```

Comment: Just load the two tables into two data frames say df1 and df2. Then use df2.groupBy().agg(coalesce, fn...) to get a new data frame df3. Finally join df1.join(df3, column/condition,"leftouter")

Comment: Hi  sramalingam24,

Comment: Hi  sramalingam24, Thank you. I was wondering if you'd be able to add more detail and give a sample code.